# Angular 4 wait till http.get execute to continue

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-web-api, promise, ionic3

I'm creating a new register form an app with Ionic and using  ASP.Net(C#) as my API.

I want to check if user exists when the input blur event is activate.

***The problem is that my code isn't waiting till the server returns a value to continue. 
What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to do that?***

**THIS IS MY API CODE:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult verifyEmail(string email)
    {
        var result = Domain.Repository.UserController.Find(email:email);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return Json(new { erro = true, message = "Email already registered!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { erro=false,message = "Email is valid!" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**I CREATED A PROVIDER TO MAKE THE HTTP REQUEST(authProvider):**

```
   getData(data,func)
    {
        return  new Promise( (resolve,reject)=>{
          this.http.get(apiUrl+func, {params:data})  
          .subscribe(
           res=>{

            resolve(res.json());
          },
          async (err)=>{
            reject(err);

          });
        });
        }
```

**AND HERE IS MY register.ts code:**

```
  validate()
  {
     let validEmail;
     validEmail= this.checkEmail();// I WANT THAT the "validEmail" receives returned value before continue.

     return true;
  }
```

**AND THE LAST THING IS MY FUNCTION THAT WILL CALL THE PROVIDER:**

```
  checkEmail()
  {
    return this.authService.getData({email:this.model.email},"Account/verifyEmail").then((result)=>{
      let response = <any>{};
      response=result;
      if(response.erro)
      {
        return response.message
      }else
      {
        return true
      }

    },(err)=>{
      this.toastService.presentToast("ERROR:"+err,"bottom",undefined,"toast-error");
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is this typescript or js?

Comment: @misha130 It doesn't matter much.

Comment: hello misha it is typescript

Comment: @LazarLjubenović someone who writes C# might like the usage of async/await. This is why i asked

Comment: how are you using `validate()`?

Comment: @SurajRao   register()
  {
    var validate = this.validate();
    if (validate=="true"){

    }else{
      this.toastService.presentToast(validate,"bottom","Fechar","toast-error");
    }
  }

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade seems like `validate()` is redundant.. you need to wait for the promise return..maybe do `if()..else` within `then()`

Comment: @SurajRao i had to transform my register function as async for it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 getData(data,func)
    {
          this.http.get(apiUrl+func, {params:data})  
          .map(res => {
            return res.json();
          })
         .toPromise();
    }
```

or with async/await

```
 async getData(data,func)
    {
     let result = await this.http.get(apiUrl+func, {params:data})  
         .toPromise();
       return result.json();
    }
```

Now for the validate function:

```
  async validate()
  {
     let validEmail;
     await this.checkEmail();
     return true;
  }
```

Point is you cant jump from a sync function to an async or vice versa. 
Validate needs to return a promise/observable because it is executes asynchronous functions.

Comment: actually async await are available in js. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). It is in [ES2017 specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-async-function-definitions)

Comment: The same thing,  the function validate() continues returning true, before  i got a result from function checkEmail()

Comment: Why would you convert it to a promise? That's going a step back from Observables.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović he likes promises. I didn't want to change it too much.

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade Editted, had to make validate() return a promise too

Comment: @misha130 let me try to run it here, i'll post if it works

Comment: @misha130 thanks for the help, altought  i had to transform my register function as async too. But now it's working, thanks a lot